# Good tool for document indexing and parsing?

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, full-text-search, documents

I was wondering what is a good tool to use to index documents (pdf, xml, web documents) etc.
I want to be able to index them, parse them and return results appropriately.

I tried solr/lucene but i must be missing something because I did not find it useful enough.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I did not find it useful enough."

Comment: The thing with Solr was that when I tried creating index, it would index the whole document in a large string. A search query on this would return the whole document too. Since that was the field that was index. I couldn't figure out a way to index within the text index.

Comment: Essentially if I <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> What's happening is that in this "content" field the entire document as one string gets indexed. That is a problem. Since my requirement is to return the string i searched for along with a few lines around it.

Comment: It seems like Lucene can only tell me in which field it occurred, not where in the field it occurred.

Comment: This should get you started witj the highlight you need: http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/05/26/accessing-words-around-a-positional-match-in-lucene/

Comment: If you don't want to bother with search you could try search as a service applications like http://IndexDen.com (I am a founder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is what you want.... ElasticSearch is an option.